# Am I losing memory allocation?

Tags: c, malloc, valgrind

I am needing to use malloc to pass the final char * to another function. 
Valgrind is complaining at me for not initalising *temp, so I have usede malloc.
The problem I than have is the memory not being allocated?
I have been fiddling around with this and cannot figure out how to fix it.

Am I losing the memory allocation during the for loop for temp?

And then again with sprintf for newCatID?

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

```
char *allocateCategoryID(ThisType *menu)
{
    char catID[ID_LEN]="";
    char *temp;
    char *newCatID;
    char *end;
    int idNum=0;
    int i=0;
    int j = 0;
    temp = malloc(ID_LEN-1);
    newCatID = malloc(ID_LEN*sizeof(char));

    /*get catID which strlen(catID)= ID_LEN*/


    for(i=1; i<ID_LEN; i++)/*FIRST VALGRIND ERROR IS HERE*/
    {
        temp[j]= catID[i];
        j++;
    }

    idNum = strtol(temp, &end, 10);/*NEXT VALGRIND ERROR IS HERE*/
    idNum++;

    sprintf(newCatID, "C%04i", idNum);/*NEXT VALGRIND ERROR IS HERE*/

    printf("New Category ID: %s\n", newCatID);/*NEXT VALGRIND ERROR IS HERE*/
    free(temp);
    return newCatID;
}

Invalid write of size 1
0 bytes after a block of 4 alloc'd
Invalid read of size 1
0 bytes after a block of 5 alloc'd
Invalid write of size 1
0 bytes after a block of 5 alloc'd
Invalid read of size 1
0 bytes after a block of 5 alloc'd
```

Comment: You are probably missing the space for the 0-terminator. Also, starting a loop index from 1 looks suspicious – do you know that array indices in C start from 0, not from 1?

Comment: Why are you copying from `catID`, which at that point is an empty string? And why do you start that copying at index `1`?

Comment: `temp[j]= catID[i];` i goes 1 to ID_LEN-1, j goes from 0 to ID_LEN-1. j should go 0 to ID_LEN-2 because temp will have ID_LEN -1 memory allocated

Comment: @askmish But since `i` starts at `1` and `j` starts at `0`, that means `j` will go to `ID_LEN - 2`.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Oh, I missed that.

Comment: If you want to copy from the second character in a string, properly *as a string* then you can still use `strcpy`: `strcpy(temp, catID + 1)`. ***But remember that `temp` needs space for the string terminator.***

Comment: That depends completely how you initialize the structure member, and how you read the data.

Comment: Then use e.g. `memcpy` instead: `memcpy(temp, catID + 1, ID_LEN - 1)`. Then you need to add the terminator to `temp` as you treat `temp` as a string (with `strtol`). Also, why are you allocating `temp` dynamically? You know the size at compile time, so why not simply make it an array of `ID_LEN` character (more specifically `ID_LEN - 1 + 1`, `-1` because it's a character smaller, then `+1` for terminator).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the last iteration of this loop:

```
for(i=1; i<ID_LEN; i++)/*FIRST VALGRIND ERROR IS HERE*/
{
    temp[j]= catID[i];
    j++;
}
```

you go out of bounds because you allocate space for `LEN - 1` in

```
temp = malloc(ID_LEN-1);
```

Change to

```
temp = malloc(ID_LEN);

for(i = 1; i < ID_LEN; i++)
{
    temp[j] = catID[i];
    j++;
}
/* here you need to add the trailing '\0' */
temp[j] = '\0';
```

Comment: Nitpicking: since the `i` starts at `1`, and the `j` starts at `0`, then the last `j` written will be `ID_LEN - 2`, and the loop exits with `j == ID_LEN - 1`.  So the loop is not the issue.  It appears that `catID[]` is not itself `'\0'` terminated, so the real issue is, indeed, that `temp[]` needs space for the `'\0'` which must be added for `strtol(temp, ...)` to work.